# I run "npx cap run android" but get stuck at Deploying app-debug.apk to Pixel_3_API_31

Tags: javascript

I'm converting a React app to an android one. I run "npx cap run android" but get stuck at Deploying app-debug.apk to Pixel_3_API_31
another terminal opens and runs qemu-system-i386.exe, there is the following output, "[23376:18372:0619/124312.874:ERROR:broker_win.cc(55)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)"

```
npm --version 8.5.5
node --version 16.15.0
capacitor/cli: 3.6.0
capacitor/core: 3.6.0
capacitor/android: 3.6.0
capacitor/ios: 3.5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

[capacitor issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5700)

I solved this problem using [this suggestion](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5700#issuecomment-1419831533)

I removed the old simulator device and created a new one. I replaced the Pixel 4 for a Pixel XL (Both API 33) and it worked